# JSSOR slider Bootstrap min-height problems?

Tags: jssor

http://coloroflaw.byethost9.com/forum (the slider above the timer !!)

the bootstrap seems to work ok, but on that server, the rescale does not seem to work as well as on another server, ie, when you resize the window the slides resize but the images dont seem to. When you reload the page then the resize kicks in.
(maybe a minify problem, i need to recheck)

My problem on two servers is that the min-height is set but images' min-height is not rendered. is it bootstrap problem? i think the parent element is set at the min-height since you can see the space

can anyone help?

```
<div style="min-height: 150px;">
    <!-- Jssor Slider Begin -->
    <div id="slider1_container" style="display: none; position: relative; margin: 0 auto; width: 980px; height: 380px; overflow: hidden;">
        ...
    </div>
    <!-- Jssor Slider End --> </div>
```

Comment: jssor slider will always keep aspect ratio while scale. so min-height is not reasonable.

Comment: isnt there a stretch option? wish you would activate it for full responsiveness :P

$FillMode=0

Comment: Also why wont it stretch the width on that server, WITHOUT RELOADING THE PAGE? the code is identical as on another server?